# file synchronisation with central database

Tags: windows, database, file-synchronization

I'm looking for a file synchroiniasion on W10 like Synctoy, NextCloud or FreeFileSync. However, I want a central database that stores the data for deletions and renames. FreeFileSync, NextCloud, and SyncToy store this information in a file in the root directories that are being synced. I do not want these extra files but a central database.

Preferably free, but I could pay up to $49.

Comment: Must it be [tag:gratis], or do you have a budget in mind?

Comment: If it costs something, it's fine.

Comment: Can you define "something"? Is $100, 000 to much? Is $99 to much?

Comment: $49 is acceptable

Comment: By central database, do you mean one database for all the folders on a given system that need to be synced, or one for all the folders across all systems?

Comment: It would be nice, but not necessary, across all systems. For me it is important that the files in the root directories disappear and are in a central directory. The so-called database can also consist of more than one file.